# Python on MacOS "dyld: Library not loaded" - error

Tags: python, macos, installation, shared-libraries

I am trying to run a python script that executes few API calls and Kafka logic but getting following error:
`dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python`

Tried `brew update && brew upgrade` and also with both Python2 and Python3 but still getting same error.
What could be the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: That message often comes with a few more lines, stating the reason why  the library was not loaded. Do you get those lines? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Hi @cikavladimir, were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hi I got this issue too after brew upgrade, I solved with delete virtualenv

```
find myvirtualenv -type l -delete
```

then recreate virtualenv

```
virtualenv myvirtualenv
```

Reference:

http://www.jeremycade.com/python/osx/homebrew/2015/03/02/fixing-virtualenv-after-a-python-upgrade/

Answer (score 5):

[The issue is related to hombrew Python installs/upgrade](http://www.jeremycade.com/python/osx/homebrew/2015/03/02/fixing-virtualenv-after-a-python-upgrade/).

Anyone who is using [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) (and you should!) can simply use these two commands — without having the venv activated:

```
rm -rf `pipenv --venv` # remove the broken venv
pipenv install --dev   # reinstall the venv from pipfile
```

Comment: I'd recommend poetry over pipenv - https://python-poetry.org/ - if you're into these tools, but recreating a virtualenv is not a hard task without these either

Comment: why the spam link in your answer?