# Python 3.7: Library not loaded

Tags: python, python-3.7

I downloaded and installed Python 3.7 macOS 64-bit installer from

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/

I have the IDLE, so I know I installed python.
However, when I try to check the version I have on terminal, it appears:

```
$ python -v
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/EmiPaz/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python on MacOS "dyld: Library not loaded" - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132419/python-on-macos-dyld-library-not-loaded-error)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190984/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-preventing-virtualenv-from-loading