# How do I handle the python3.8.4 virtual environment problem for image not found

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm developing a vscode language extension. The extension has a Python language server. I build this server using Python 3.8.4. I created a python virtual environment by virtualenv. I think the server should run by the python3.8 which is in the virtual environment.

I use  `vsce package` to generate the VSIX file.

The extension can work on my computer and my friend's computer whose Python version is 3.8.4. But when my other friends tried to install my extension, the error below showed up:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Python
 Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/path/env/bin/python3
 Reason: image not found
```

Their python version is not 3.8.4.  I want my extension can run without caring for the python version. Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132419/python-on-macos-dyld-library-not-loaded-error

Comment: I follow the answer with the highest score. But image not found error happens again when the system python version is not 3.7/